# What does "hit a natural" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Schindler's List (1993)*, with Goeth, Oskar Schindler gambles with a deck of cards in a game of Twenty-One for his maid -
he proposes to put Helen's name in the last line left on the final page:

> Oskar: One hand of 21.
>
> Goeth: No.
>
> Oskar: If you win, I pay you 7,400 reichsmarks.  **Hit a natural**, I make
> it 14,800.
>
> Goeth: No.

What does "hit a natural" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the game "blackjack", "vingt-un" or "twenty-one", the idea is to be dealt cards totalling as close to 21 points as possible, without exceeding it. The player is dealt two cards to start, and can ask for more cards to get closer to 21. If the total goes over 21, the player loses.
If the player gets exactly 21 on the first two cards dealt, that is a natural and wins the hand.

[Wikipedia "Blackjack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack)

"If the player is dealt an Ace and a ten-value card (called a "blackjack" or "**natural**"), and the dealer does not, the player wins and usually receives a bonus."